# Arrays with non-inline style formulas in rows in KaTeX

Tags: arrays, fractions, inline, mathjax

I'm having a hard time trying to get a properly aligned inequations involving fractions in KaTeX. The best output I have got is with the `array` environment:

```
\begin{array}{crccclc}
z\in\Bbb R^+, & 0 &\le& x-z\ffrac{x}{z} &\lt& z & (8)\\[3pt]
& z\ffrac{x}{z} &\le& x &\lt& (z+1)\ffrac{x}{z}  &(9)
\end{array}
```

[image]

The problem is the array environment displays formulas in inline style. How could I force arrays to print fractions, sums, etc, in a non-inline style so they take more height?

Comment: The horizontal spacing is not good.

Comment: @Sebastiano I know. Does this site allow questions abouts KaTeX?

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks, I didn't know mathjax and KaTeX were the same thing, although I knew they are, strictly spoken, different from LaTeX/TeX.

Comment: @Sebastiano katex-specific questions, like mathjax-specific questions are off topic (as they are javascript) but if the question can be phrased so it also applies to latex it can of course be on topic.

Comment: @Sebastiano your comment is basically misleading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm deleting my comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that KaTeX has the `darray` environment that does exactly what I'm asking for.

Comment: @Sebastiano mathjax and katex are not related.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hi, I delete my comments on KaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

For those who don't use KaTeX, here's an answer that use the `alignat` environment of the `amsmath` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amssymb,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\newcommand\ffrac[2]{\floor*{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{$\displaystyle x-z\ffrac{x}{z}$} % measure width of middle part

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4}
z\in\Bbb{R}^+, &\quad& 0 &\le{}&& x-z\ffrac{x}{z} &{}<{}& z \\[1ex]
               && z\ffrac{x}{z} &\le{}&& \parbox{\mylen}{\centering$x$} &{}<{}& (z+1)\ffrac{x}{z} 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you add the formula numbering at the end of each line? Does `alignat` add them automatically in LaTeX? KaTeX have a similar environment called `alignedat` but it doesn't add them.

Comment: @Peregring-lk - I'm afraid I'm not familiar with KaTeX. The `amsmath` package provides environments called `align`, `alignat`, `aligned`, and `alignedat`. The former two are standalone environments that provide equation numbering; the latter two are meant to be used inside a larger, encasing environment and do not provide their own numbering mechanism.

Comment: Don't be afraid.

Answer (score 4):

A variant of @Mico's solution, using the  `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` command, from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\ffrac}[2]{\lfloor}{\rfloor}{\frac{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{7}

\begin{alignat}{3}
z\in\Bbb R^+, \qquad 0 &\le x- & & z\ffrac*{x}{z} & & < z \\[3pt]
 z\ffrac*{x}{z} &\le & & x & & < (z+1)\ffrac[\bigg]{x}{z}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I add a small answer (it similar to a comment). I suggest to use this link https://katex.org/docs/support_table.html, a simple guide of `KaTeX` specific for the table.

---

[image]

---

```
\begin{darray}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & d
\end{darray}
```

In the left bar you can find also the guide of `KaTeX`. I add also a link of `MathJaX` that it is used in Math.SE:

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference